# How to get a total number of occurrences in an IF statement

Tags: if-statement, count

After looking at a bunch of the other questions similar to mine, I found one that partially works but not exactly as I need it to. I am trying to get a total for the number of times an occurrence is found in my IF statement. The code I have tried is below:

```
for i in data['resources']:
    url = server+ "/api/3/assets/" +str(i)
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify=False)
    data = response.json()
    Total = 0
    if data['red'] and data['blue'] > 0:
        Total += 1
        print('Total:', Total)
```

Rather than giving me an output like:

```
Total: 3
```

I get this:

```
Total: 1
Total: 1
Total: 1
```

Comment: I dont understand. Is this inside a loop ? its an IF statement and it executes only once and then total becomes 1.

Comment: @rootkonda my apologies, i have updated the code. let me know if this helps

Comment: Total=0 is inside the loop right then it will reset it everytime to 0. You have to put it outside the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total=0 inside the for loop and getting reset for each iteration. So you have to put Total=0 outside the for loop. And also if you want it to print only once then put the Print statement outside and at the end of the for loop

I am sure this should solve your problem